# 'Identical' Strings are different

Tags: php, string, wordpress, utf-8

I have 2 strings `"CHILDREN’S"`.

One of them is saved to a MySQL database (in fact it's a page title, from WordPress). The other is a copy and pasted version of the string from the database.

When I run `var_dump` on the 2 strings ( `var_dump("CHILDREN’S"); var_dump($string)`), the copy-pasted one is `string(12) "CHILDREN’S"` and the one displayed from the database is `string(16) "CHILDREN’S"`. I'm assuming that this is a UTF-8 issue.

Can someone shed some light on why the identical strings are in fact not identical.

Comment: Could you possibly have whitespace around the visible text, or a non visible character somewhere inside the string?

Comment: Most likely you have a unicode character there.

Comment: well that apostrophe character certainly isn't a `'`.

Comment: Don't copy and paste for the browser , View The HTML code then copy and paste the text here .. you would bee able to see the hidden characters

Comment: have you checked it isn't a HTML entity -- ie `&#xxxx;` in one version? (try 'view source' on the page when you do the `var_dump()` to be sure) that would be big enough to make up the difference in the string length.

Answer (score 1):

"CHILDREN'S" is ten characters. To make it 12, the "'" must become an UTF-8 codepoint and that's OK.

But I see no way to get 16 characters unless the second quote is really a `&rsquo;`. There are no seven-bytes encodings that I know of except HTML entity.

If it is so, then `html_entity_decode` could be your friend.

Comment: `&quot;` is not a `’`, it's a standard double quote character.

Comment: You're totally right. I seem to not be able to count up to seven: `&quot;` would have been SIX characters, and replacing one in ten to get sixteen required SEVEN. Truth is, I have never really bothered remembering all the myriad quoting marks there are out there. Were it up to me, I'd stick with good old ASCII 0x27.

Answer (score 0):

This could either be an encoding problem, in which case you will want to check the database column's encoding and make sure it is what you expect it is.

Alternatively, you may have a couple of non-printable characters in the database string -- it could be that you copy/pasted some kind of nasty characters from your database tool.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's actually stored as an HTML entity in one of the versions of the string.

If it's stored as `&rsquo;` rather than an actual `’` character, then it is obviously a different string length.

Bear in mind also that PHP's `strlen()` function is not multi-byte safe. If you've got unicode characters in there, you should probably use the `mb_strlen()` function instead if you want an accurate character count. This would account for why even your shorter character count is 12, when the string actually only contains 10 characters.

The additional four characters in the other copy are probably due to an HTML entity.

Answer (score 0):

To see how the strings really differ, you could write the hex out of every string.

For example:

```
$s1 = 'CHILDREN\'S';

for($i=0; $i<strlen($s1); $i++)
  echo '0x' . bin2hex(substr($s1, $i, 1)) . ' ';
```

This gives `0x43 0x48 0x49 0x4c 0x44 0x52 0x45 0x4e 0x27 0x53` as a result. Try the same with the string from the database, and see where it differs.